# Primefaces commandButton asynchronous actions not fired

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

i have a Primefaces application in which i fire up a dialog that contains a form. The dialog has a save/cancel button-pair. Within this dialog, i do not manage to have the oncomplete, onstart, etc., methods called. I saw on other replies the cause is no AJAX is being executed. However, i do not know the reason in this case, since the commandButton is of type submit and should have ajax="true" (by default). Can anyone put a bit of light in it?

My xhtml:

```
     <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="bean" required="true"/>
     </composite:interface>

     <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputScript library="careplan" name="js/utils.js" />

        <p:dialog id="addEventDialog" widgetVar="addEventDialog" header="#{careplanMessages['panel.title.eventAdd']}" modal="true" resizable="false">
           <h:form id="eventAddForm" widgetVar="eventAddForm">
              <p:fieldset legend="#{careplanMessages['label.field.data']}" >
                 <h:panelGrid id="formGrid" widgetVar="formGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel for="parentNode">#{careplanMessages['label.field.parentNode']}</p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText id="parentNode" label="#{careplanMessages['label.field.parentNode']}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.parentNode}" required="true"/>

                    <p:outputLabel for="name">#{careplanMessages['label.field.eventName']}</p:outputLabel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                       <p:inputText id="name" label="#{careplanMessages['label.field.eventName']}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.name}" required="true" />
                       <p:message for="name" display="icon" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:outputLabel for="description">#{careplanMessages['label.field.description']}</p:outputLabel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                       <p:inputTextarea id="description" label="#{careplanMessages['label.field.description']}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.description}" rows="6" cols="33" required="true"/>
                       <p:message for="description" display="icon" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:outputLabel for="minutes">#{careplanMessages['label.field.minutes']}</p:outputLabel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                       <p:spinner id="minutes" label="#{careplanMessages['label.field.minutes']}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.minutes}" min="0">
                          <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1.0" />
                       </p:spinner>
                       <p:message for="minutes" display="icon" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:outputLabel for="active">#{careplanMessages['label.field.active']}</p:outputLabel>
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="active" label="#{careplanMessages['label.field.active']}" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.active}" />
                 </h:panelGrid>
              </p:fieldset>

              <p:separator />

              <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                 <h:commandButton 
                    value="#{careplanMessages['button.save']}" 
                    onclick="alert ('onclick')" 
                    onstart="alert ('onstart')" 
                    onsuccess="alert ('onsuccess')" 
                    onerror="alert ('onerror')" 
                    oncomplete="alert ('oncomplete')"
                    styleClass="btn btn-default btn-small" />
                 <h:commandButton type="button" value="#{careplanMessages['button.cancel']}" onclick="PF ('addEventDialog').hide()" styleClass="btn btn-default btn-small" />
              </h:panelGrid>
           </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
     </composite:implementation>
  </ui:composition>
```

And here my backing bean:

```
  @ManagedBean
  @ViewScoped
  public class HouseLepEventAddBean implements Serializable {

     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger (HouseLepEventAddBean.class);

     private String name = null;
     private String parentNode = "test";
     private List <SelectItem> parentNodeList = null;
     private String description = null;
     private int minutes = 0;
     private boolean active = true;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init () {

     }

     public String getName () {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
     }

     public String getParentNode () {
        return parentNode;
     }

     public void setParentNode (String parentNode) {
        this.parentNode = parentNode;
     }

     public List <SelectItem> getParentNodeList () {
        return parentNodeList;
     }

     public void setParentNodeList (List <SelectItem> parentNodeList) {
        this.parentNodeList = parentNodeList;
     }

     public String getDescription () {
        return description;
     }

     public void setDescription (String description) {
        this.description = description;
     }

     public int getMinutes () {
        return minutes;
     }

     public void setMinutes (int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
     }

     public boolean isActive () {
        return active;
     }

     public void setActive (boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
     }
  }
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<h:commandButton>` which is a JSF component, replace that with Primefaces's `<p:commandButton>` which is AJAX-enabled by default.